# php header('Refresh: 1;url=destination'); in Flask + python?

Tags: php, python, redirect, flask, refresh

in php there is

```
header('Refresh: 1;url=destination');
```

which redirects the client to a given url, and while it must be called before anything else, it allows me to display something else after that line.

In Flask + python which I am practicing, there is

```
return redirect(destination, code=301)
```

which also redirects, but isn't able to do anything else, like displaying further code to the client as PHP can do.

If I'm not wrong, both functions send an header which says to the client to go to another location, but they behave differently: in the first case it is sent while providing an answer; in the second case, it is the answer.

I'd like to have the same (php) function in Flask but after reading the docs, I guess there isn't a way to serve a redirect together with some content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `header()` does is add a HTTP header to the response. You can do so in Flask too.

Either return a tuple of `(body, status, headers)` or return a [`flask.Response()` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#response-objects). See [*About Responses*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses) in the quickstart.

Example with a body, status and headers tuple:

```
body = render_template('sometemplate', somevar=somevalue)
return (body, 200, {'Refresh': '1;url=destination'})
```

Here the second element sets a 200 status code (success), and the third is a dictionary specifying the `Refresh` header.

Comment: Solved perfectly. Thanks Martijn